# Multiple Users in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I created a website , this website has a backend with the usual login / logout, my website also has this feature for the registered clients, however Yii is taking the same user for the website and for the backend.

If I sign out from the backend it also sign me out from the website, how can I have multiple users so this won't happen?

Answer (score 1):

You just assign roles to users. Then you do [RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/771/rbac-super-simple-with-admin-and-user/) and let those qualified (admin group) to have access to the backend, while clients not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are authenticating with Yii, that authenticated user will be the current user everywhere in Yii until you log out and someone else does.